# Passing map object to javascript function

Tags: javascript, google-maps

In order to add an offset to the center point in Google maps when a button are pressed, I try this funcion:

```
function offsetCenter(map, marker) {

var worldCoordinateCenter = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(marker.getPosition());
var pixelOffset = new google.maps.Point((100/scale) || 0,(0/scale) ||0)

var worldCoordinateNewCenter = new google.maps.Point(
    worldCoordinateCenter.x - pixelOffset.x,
    worldCoordinateCenter.y + pixelOffset.y
);

var newCenter = map.getProjection().fromPointToLatLng(worldCoordinateNewCenter);

map.setCenter(newCenter);

}


});
```

I call that funcion from infoWindows where map and marker are defined:

```
       (function(marker, data) {
              google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {

            info = '<h4>' + data.nombre + '</h4><h4>'+ data.offerta+'</h4><h4>'+ data.horario+'</h4><a href='+data.web+'><h4>Web</h4></a>'
+ '<input type="button" class = "launchConfirm" onclick="offsetCenter(\''+map+'\', \''+marker+'\');" value='Reset center'></input>'  //this is the button inside the infowindos to re-set the map center with an offset 
        ;

        infoWindow.setContent(info);   
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);

        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());   //center the map to marker
        map.setZoom(16);                       //zoom to marker

         });
      }
```

But marker and map object are not defined inside the offsetCenter function.
How can pass a map object and marker to that function?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, **Complete**, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem you are trying to fix.

Comment: I just add the complete infowindows function where inside, the button that call the "offsetCenter" function is called.

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure your 'map' variable and your marker manager are in scope >= function scope.  this way you will not need to pass in the map.
2. Use a marker manager to manage your makers. you can then add a unique id to some attribute on your link. when the click comes in you can access the object to get the id, which will allow you to retrieve the maker from the manager. so the code would look something like this:

Info Window Content(shortened for brevity):

```
var info = '<h4>' + data.nombre + '</h4>'<input type="button" data-markerId="' + SomeMarkerManager.getMarkerId() '" onclick="offsetCenter(this);" value='Reset center'></input>'  


var offsetCenter = function (element) {
  // get the marker Id
  var markerId = $(element).attr("data-marker-id");

  // use the markerId to find your marker
  var marker = SomeMarkerManager.getMarkerById(markerId);

  // now you have access to your map and the clicked marker
}
```

P.S.
marker managers are out of the scope of this answer.  Just search for google maps marker managers.